# Error: Could not cleanup old kegs! Fix your permissions on:

Tags: file-permissions, homebrew

I'm trying to run `brew cleanup`, yet running into following error:

> Error: Could not cleanup old kegs! Fix your permissions on:

---

```
% brew cleanup
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/6.6.0... (28,050 files, 364MB)
Warning: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/6.6.0
==> This operation has freed approximately 364MB of disk space.
Error: Could not cleanup old kegs! Fix your permissions on:
  /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/6.6.0
% echo $?
1
%
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to address "fix your permissions" error, one must use `chown(8)` (change file owner and group) along with `sudo(8)` (execute a command as another user), like so:

```
% sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
% echo $?
0
% brew cleanup
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/6.6.0... (28,050 files, 364MB)
==> This operation has freed approximately 364MB of disk space.
% echo $?
0
%
```